# How to insert user input into localstorage using javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can I initialize variable before execute it using javascript
The following code refer to user input to localstorage but I do have an error . any idea how to solve it.
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sorting Test</title>
<body>
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Add participant<legend>
  <input id="userID" type="text">
  <input id="userName" type="text">
  <input id="userOccupation" type="text">
  <button id="addbtn" type="button" >Add</button>
 </fieldset>


</body>
<script>
  // get the userid, userName and UserOccupation
  const userID = document.getElementById("userID");
  const userName = document.getElementById("userName");
  const userOccupation = document.getElementById("userOccupation");
  const addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");

  //add user input to storage
  addbtn.onclick = function() {
    const userID = userID.value;
    const userName = userName.value;
    const userOccupation = userOccupation.value;
    localStorage.setItem(userID, userName, userOccupation);
  };
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is about your attempt to use the _same_ identifier for a constant in the local scope, as in the outside scope. `const userID = userID.value;` - _which_ `userID` would you mean here in the second half? You need to use different names here.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same variable names in your anonymous function since you have already declared them as constants.

Either change the variables names in the anonymous function or declare your variables with `let` instead of `const` (prefer the 1st)

Comment: Using `let` wouldn't solve the problem, because he'd still be trying to access a variable before defining it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're re-defining ([shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)) your variables inside the click function.

```
const userID = document.getElementById("userID");
/* ... */

addbtn.onclick = function() {
    const userID = userID.value; // (1)
    /* ... */
};
```

At (1), `userID` is a variable inside the scope of the function, not the variable from outside. Furthermore, because this new `userID` variable that you're defining hasn't been defined yet when you're trying to access its `value` property, you're getting the error you posted.

If you change its name to something like `userIDValue`, or change the other variable's name to something like `userIDElement`, then that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
:: HTML DOC ::

 <form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name='name' id='name' placehodler='enter name' required>
    <button type="submit" id='sbt-btn'>Store in LS</button>
</form>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------  

:: JS DOC ::

//DOM fetch 
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', () => {

   const inputName = form.name.value;      //name is the input field's ID                                    
   localStorage.setItem('name', inputName); //add name to localStorage

});

//retrive name from local storage

if (localStorage.getItem('name')) {
   userName = localStorage.getItem('name');
     form.innerHTML += `<p>Hi ${userName}!</p>`;
 }

/* it will append this html template only when the local storage has a key 
'name' with some value in it. */
```